# QMainWindow destructor

Tags: qt, qmainwindow, virtual-destructor

Why the QMainWindow's destructor is not virtual? If I inherit a class MainWindow from QMainWindow and have some pointer attribute on it I can't delete the memory using MainWindow's destructor.

Answer (score 6):

QMainWindow's destructor is an override of an already existing destructor (`QWidget::~QWidget()`) which in turn is an override of a virtual destructor (`virtual QObject::~QObject()`). Thus, `QMainWindow::~QMainWindow()` is virtual. The same rules apply as with normal member functions.

Answer (score 4):

QObject's destructor has been declared as virtual. QMainWindow is derived from QObject indirectly. I belive QMainWindow's destruct does not need virtual in this case.  Did you set breakpoint in QMainWindow's destructor while deleting your derived class?

Comment: This is correct, if the base class's destructor is virtual all inherited classes implicitly have a virtual destructor whether they ask for it or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is a defect in Qt (failure to adhere to CBP); it is best practice to always carry-over modifiers, especially virtual, in all derived classes, exactly to avoid this kind of problem.

NOT carrying-over the the virtual declaration means that, as a user, I have to not just lookup the class, but also ALL it's parents, to make sure the method(s) I want to override are virtual or not. A little laziness by the developers costs me lots of time.

Arguments about 'maintainability' are irrelevant; it makes the class harder to use (there will be many, MANY more users than maintainers...)